# How to differentiate not set parameter from $false, 0, empty string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have function that updates object in WMI. I want user to be able to specify in parameters only values that he wants to update. How can I do it?

```
function UpdateObject ([bool] $b1, [bool] $b2, [int] $n1, [string] $s1)
{
    $myObject = GetObjectFromWmi #(...)
    #(...)

    #This is bad. As it overrides all the properties.
    $myObject.b1 = $b1
    $myObject.b2 = $b2
    $myObject.n1 = $n1
    $myObject.s1 = $s1

    #This is what I was thinking but don't kwow how to do
    if(IsSet($b1)) { $myObject.b1 = $b1 }
    if(IsSet($b2)) { $myObject.b2 = $b2 }
    if(IsSet($n1)) { $myObject.n1 = $n1 }
    if(IsSet($s1)) { $myObject.s1 = $s1 }

    #(...) Store myObject in WMI.
}
```

I tried passing `$null` as as parameter but it get's automaticly converted to `$false` for `bool`, `0` for `int` and `empty string` for `string`

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Automatic_Variables?view=powershell-5.1) to see if it contains a key with the name of your parameter:

```
if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('b1')) { $myObject.b1 = $b1 }
if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('b2')) { $myObject.b2 = $b2 }
if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('n1')) { $myObject.n1 = $n1 }
if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('s1')) { $myObject.s1 = $s1 }
```

`$PSBoundParameters` acts like a hashtable, where the keys are the parameter names, and the values are the parameters' values, but it only contains *bound* parameters, which means parameters that are explicitly passed. It *does not contain* parameters filled in with a default value (except for those passed with `$PSDefaultParameterValues`).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Building on [briantist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571872/712649), if you know that all the parameters exist as properties on the target object you can simply loop through the `$PSBoundParameters` hashtable and add them one by one:

```
foreach($ParameterName in $PSBoundParameters.Keys){
    $myObject.$ParameterName = $PSBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
}
```

---

If only *some* of the input parameters are to be passed as property values, you can still specify the list just once, with:

```
$PropertyNames = 'b1','b2','n1','s1'
foreach($ParameterName in $PSBoundParameters.Keys |Where-Object {$PropertyNames -contains $_}){
    $myObject.$ParameterName = $PSBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
}
```

Comment: That is neat. There are some more arguments to that function and I don't need that in many places. But take my up vote as that is indeed neat solution I'll probably use in future.

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself having to create a parameter for each property you *may* want to change, consider using a hashtable or other object to pass this information to your function.

For example:

```
function UpdateObject ([hashtable]$properties){

    $myObject = GetObjectFromWmi

    foreach($property in $properties.Keys){

        # without checking
         $myObject.$property = $properties.$property

        # with checking (assuming members of the wmiobject have MemberType Property.
        if($property -in (($myObject | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "Property"}).Name)){
            Write-Output "Updating $property to $($properties.$property)"
            $myObject.$property = $properties.$property
        }else{
            Write-Output "Property $property not recognised"
        }

    }
}

UpdateObject -properties {"b1" = $true; "b2" = $false}
```

Comment: Personally, I think this approach weakens your function. It makes sense when you don't know what parameters are supposed to be at design time, when they're dynamic, but it circumvents all of the stuff PowerShell does to manage parameters, and makes all of that less discoverable. It breaks auto-generated help, etc.

Comment: @briantist Thanks for the feedback. I found your answer closest to what OP is after so +1'd. Also agree it's preferable given a small number of parameters, when parameters are known and for built-in parameter benefits. However, in similar situations I've found creating parameters for every property that may be changed (and updating down the line)  a nightmare. Especially when considering a large number of properties which AFAIK is the case across WmiObjects. In that case, I prefer the versatility of hashtables as really the restriction is on `GetObjectFromWmi` (using OP's example)

Comment: If the intent is really to support every possible WMI property, or a large portion of them, then I'd agree. If a wrapper function supports a specific known purpose though, then I think it's better to explicitly create the parameters. Since the example function isn't being a passed an object to update, or information about retrieving a (variable) object type, but instead retrieves an object within it (without using the params passed), it seems most likely that the WMI obj type is known, so to me seems more appropriate to explicitly declare. It's obv. an example func though so who knows!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `[Boolean]` parameter that you want the user to specify explicitly or omit (rather than a `[Switch]` parameter which can be present or not), you can use `[Nullable[Boolean]]`. Example:

```
function Test-Boolean {
  param(
    [Nullable[Boolean]] $Test
  )

  if ( $Test -ne $null ) {
    if ( $Test ) {
      "You specified -Test `$true"
    }
    else {
      "You specified -Test `$false"
    }
  }
  else {
    "You did not specify -Test"
  }
}
```

In this sample function the `$Test` variable will be `$null` (user did not specify the parameter), `$true` (user specified `-Test $true`), or `$false` (user specified `-Test $false`). If user specifies `-Test` without a parameter argument, PowerShell will throw an error.

In other words: This gives you a tri-state `[Boolean]` parameter (missing, explicitly true, or explicitly false). `[Switch]` only gives you two states (present or explicitly true, and absent or explicitly false).